# how to get multiple sliders values when using onValuechange

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 3 sliders that I want to read their value, when using on Value Change event I can read the value of one of these 3 sliders like this

```
public Slider verticalSlider;
 float verticalValue = 0f;

 public void ReadSliderValue()
{
    float value    = verticalSlider.value;
    float maxValue = verticalSlider.maxValue;
    float minValue = verticalSlider.minValue;
   
   
    verticalValue = verticalSlider.value;
}
```

but this method only allow one slider at a time and making a function for each slider doesn't seem very conventional. so are there any better solutions?

Comment: Let the three components go to the same trigger event, and then use **this.value** to get it?

Comment: @HanHan There is no reference to the Slider's Unity Event so there is no `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can't. But it's not impossible.

This is one of my frustrations as well. There is no UI object referencing in events. That means you need a separate event for each UI control. So that means that for sound settings you need `OnMusicVolumeChange()` and `OnSFXVolumeChange()`. You can't do `OnVolumeChange(UI)` and check `if UI == SFX`.

However, there is a workaround if you use a forwarder.
For this proof-of-concept, I'll assume an empty scene. Yes, you read right, this implementation will work on any scene, no matter how many UI sliders you have or what name they have. But so we can test, I'll name them separately so you can also output the text and be assured it works properly.

Let's write the code that we need for the forwarder (I'll explain it further below):

The Unity event class:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class EventWithSlider : UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent<UnityEngine.UI.Slider> {}
```

The trigger class (yes, the `?` is not a typo, it's correct for it to be there)

```
public class EventWithSliderTrigger : UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour
{
    [UnityEngine.SerializeField] EventWithSlider m_Event;

    private void Awake()
    {
        UnityEngine.UI.Slider slider = GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Slider>();
        slider.onValueChanged.RemoveAllListeners();
        slider.onValueChanged.AddListener((System.Single nothing) => { m_Event?.Invoke(GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Slider>()); });
    }
}
```

And lastly, your actual script that reads values:

```
public class ValueChangeTest : UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour
{
    public void ReadSliderValue(UnityEngine.UI.Slider slider)
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log(slider.gameObject.name + " * " + slider.value + " * " + slider.minValue + " * " + slider.maxValue);
    }
}
```

Now, I add some 2 game objects: 1 slider and an anonymous `GameObject` where I place `ValueChangeTest`.

Now, the setup:

1. as I said, I attach `ValueChangeTest` on the anonymous `GameObject`
2. I attach `EventWithSliderTrigger` on the Slider GO.
3. I **do not** attach `EventWithSlider` anywhere, I **do not** reference it anywhere, no get-function for it, nothing. in fact, I don't even care it exists.
4. Now, on the slider GO do the following: *On Value Changed (Single)` trigger make sure you have NOTHING (I also delete all listeners from code, but it's better to not show anything in the Inspector to not confuse you)
5. In the Inspector, on the "Event With Slider Trigger" script, at the "Event (Slider)" trigger, reference the anonymous `GameObject` and your `ReadSliderValue` function; don't choose anything on the Slider itself
6. Duplicate the Slider 3 times, I called them "Slider1", "Slider2", "Slider3"; I also changed the min and max values to each to make sure they are displayed correctly (I set 0 - 0.3 for S1, 0.4 - 0.7 for S2 and 0.8 - 1 for S3).
7. Go to PlayMode, modify the slider inside the Scene View (not the Inspector) and watch the console output the values for each Slider in the same function

## OK, so what did I code?

I wrote my own `UnityEvent` class that takes a UI slider as a parameter: `EventWithSlider`.
Next, because this is not part of the workflow, I had to add it to the workflow, by using a sort of a forwarding class: a `MonoBehaviour` that triggers it (or better said, *invokes* it): `EventWithSliderTrigger`.

## Why does it work?

The magic is in `EventWithSliderTrigger.Awake()`, more specifically:

```
slider.onValueChanged.RemoveAllListeners();
slider.onValueChanged.AddListener((System.Single nothing) => { m_Event?.Invoke(GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Slider>()); });
```

The first line removes any trigger (or rather *listener*), the second one adds my own event to the workflow. Which part of the workflow? The slider event when the value changes.

So basically, what happens is this: my new MB trigger removes any "old style" event calls that we can't use (the ones that only have the value) and adds a new trigger call (with the slider itself as parameter). The trigger calls the new event and the event is configured to call `ValueChangeTest.ReadSliderValue()`. Next, duplicating the GOs made Unity automatically update the references to know the game object it needs to reference (and the slider, implicitly) is each duplicated instance. So if you duplicated the first slider, you won't get the first slider on all three calls.

Minor caveats to make this work in case you missed it:

1. remove `public Slider verticalSlider;` from your `MonoBehaviour`. You don't need it.
2. `public void ReadSliderValue()` becomes `public void ReadSliderValue(UnityEngine.UI.Slider slider)` so it can actually receive the slider reference.

## So, what changed? What's the impact?

So for short, the way you implement this in your game has almost no changes. The only changes are:

1. you add the `EventWithSliderTrigger` component that didn't exist before
2. instead of adding events to the `Slider`, you add them to the `EventWithSliderTrigger` (and the `Slider` will have no more events)

So this is almost no impact to how you handle Sliders if you wish to receive the event from multiple Sliders on the same instance of the script.